# How to insert a json array data into mysql in node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json

My json be like :

```
var data = [ {month: 1, customer: 11, revenue: 200},
             {month: 2, customer: 13, revenue: 210}
           ];
```

But when I inserted it into database using sql query
`"INSERT into t1 VALUES (data)"`, 
I got error : `{"code":"ER_INVALID_JSON_TEXT","errno":3140,"sqlMessage":"Invalid JSON text: \"Invalid value.\" at position 1 in value for column t1.data`

How should the correct query syntax be like? Any answer will be very appreciated

Comment: it would be `.query('INSERT into t1 VALUES (?)', [JSON.stringify(data)])`

Answer (score 5):

The reason you got the error is it has to be valid json text

I.e the key names have to be in '' Quotation marks as well as values if they are not numeric 
Here is json string tester to check the validity of your json [json validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)

Then stringify your data and save it

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
var responseJson = JSON.stringify(data.response);

var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO table SET column=?', responseJson, 
 function(err, result) {
 if(err) throw err;
 console.log('data inserted');
 });
```

Comment: Hi JonoJames, by using that json validator, my data is valid. the only thing i need is to stringify my data. And it worked

Comment: I do not think SET will work here . He is trying insert multiple rows.

Comment: Yea Set will work as you run your set in a loop outside of the query .and loop the query multiple times

Answer (score 1):

If You Want to Insert the data in to database  which is in the form of Json Array,
So its very easy to Insert data and no need to stringfy the data or doing any other Operations. I am Providing you a Simplest Way of doing this . Lets See...

1. I have a data which i am storing in an variable users.

```js
let users = [
  {
    "Email": "rachel@example.com",
    "EmployeeId": "9012",
    "Firstname": "Rachel",
    "Lastname": "Booker",
    "Department": "Sales",
    "Location": "Manchester"
  }, {
    "Email": "laura@example.com",
    "EmployeeId": "2070",
    "Firstname": "Laura",
    "Lastname": "Grey",
    "Department": "Depot",
    "Location": "London"
  }, {
    "Email": "craig@example.com",
    "EmployeeId": "4081",
    "Firstname": "Craig",
    "Lastname": "Johnson",
    "Department": "Depot",
    "Location": "London"
  },
];
```

Now that Bulk data I am going to Insert on Mysql Database. You can choose whatever You want but care for insert query.

2. The Code is ==>

```js
let sql = `insert ignore into employee values?`;

let values = [];

//an empty array and push the data in to values array using for loop.
//I have already created a table "Employee" with column name which is I am pushing //Data in same Manner.Note :- (Remember While Pushing data which will same Order as Your table column name)

//for loop is running till the length of the users;

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  values.push([users[i].Email, users[i].EmployeeId, users[i].Firstname, users[i].Lastname, users[i].Department, users[i].Location])
}

//Now Running the query (here con is a variable of database );

con.query(sql, [values], (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("rows affected " + result.affectedRows);
});
```

try this its ver easy No any long Code any no any bug.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add an array to mysql, you need to form the correct query
Insert multiple rows has the following syntax:
INSERT INTO tableName(column1, column2, column3) VALUES
(1, 11, 200), // row 1
(2, 13, 210) // row 2

In your case, you can create a request as follows:

```
const sqlQuery = `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ` + data.map({month, customer, revenue} => `(${month}, ${customer}, ${revenue})`).join(',');

// if you use mysql client

var query = connection.query(sqlQuery, (err) => {
   if(err) throw err;
   console.log('data inserted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the array in an array for bulk insertion

```
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO table SET column=?', [data], 
 function(err, result) {
 if(err) throw err;
 console.log('data inserted');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping me. 
I only need to stringfy my data then it works.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

this return

```
 '[{\"month\":11,\"year\":2019,\"customer\":10,\"revenue\":0},
   {\"month\":12,\"year\":2019,\"customer\":0,\"revenue\":100}]'
```

then I inserted it simply by `"INSERT INTO table VALUES (json);"`

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this simple solution for this case which works for me:

**my-model.js**

```
exports.insert = async dataObj => {
  try {
    const TABLE_NAME = 'my-table';

    // mysql table fields
    const ARR_TABLE_FIELDS = ['ds_prop', 'ds_otherprop', 'created_at'];
    
    // mysql table values which only needs the values
    const ARR_VALUES = Object.entries(dataObj).map(keyValue => {
      // keyValue arg is an array
      // which provides the value in the second position
      return `'${keyValue[1]}'`
    });

    // mysql-handler will retrieve the data id
    const tableId = await mysqlHandler.insert(TABLE_NAME, ARR_TABLE_FIELDS, ARR_VALUES);

    return tableId;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};
```

**mysql-handler.js**
using [NodeJS v12](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v12.19.1/)+ and npm package [mysql2 version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) `2.2.5`

```
  async insert(tableName, arrFields, arrValues) {

    const query = `INSERT INTO ${tableName} (${arrFields.toString()}) VALUES (${arrValues.toString()}, CURRENT_TIME())`;
    const response = await this.db.query(query);

    let id;

    if (response && Array.isArray(response) && response[0] && response[0].affectedRows > 0) {
      id = response[0].insertId;
    }

    return id;
  }
```