# INSERT JSON array into MYSQL Database with NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

i'm trying to pump a JSON array into a MYSQL Database, i already found something similiar but the Solution is not working for me.
[Similiar issue i found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944744/how-to-insert-a-json-array-data-into-mysql-in-node-js)

Here is my try of first stringify the body from the Request and after that push that via

```
INSERT INTO table SET ?
```

Table is created like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.AStockHistory 
( Symbol text NOT NULL, 
Date timestamp NOT NULL, 
Open double, 
High double, 
Low double, 
Close double, 
Volume double, 
Dividends double, 
Stock_Splits double );
```

my Code from NodeJS:

```
async function create(stockHistory){

  var data = JSON.stringify(stockHistory);
  const result = await db.query(
    `INSERT INTO db.AStockHistory SET ?`, data); 
  return {message};
}
```

Here is my full JSON array i try to push via postman. The gereated structure of the JSON is made by a pandas dataframe.

```
 [
  {
    Symbol: 'msft',
    Date: '2022-07-20 00:00:00',
    Open: 259.8999938965,
    High: 264.8699951172,
    Low: 258.9100036621,
    Close: 262.2699890137,
    Volume: 22788300,
    Dividends: 0,
    Stock_Splits: 0
  },
  {
    Symbol: 'msft',
    Date: '2022-07-21 00:00:00',
    Open: 259.7900085449,
    High: 264.8900146484,
    Low: 257.0299987793,
    Close: 264.8399963379,
    Volume: 22404700,
    Dividends: 0,
    Stock_Splits: 0
  },
  {
    Symbol: 'msft',
    Date: '2022-07-22 00:00:00',
    Open: 265.2399902344,
    High: 265.3299865723,
    Low: 259.0700073242,
    Close: 260.3599853516,
    Volume: 21871000,
    Dividends: 0,
    Stock_Splits: 0
  },
  {
    Symbol: 'msft',
    Date: '2022-07-25 00:00:00',
    Open: 261,
    High: 261.5,
    Low: 256.8099975586,
    Close: 258.8299865723,
    Volume: 21056000,
    Dividends: 0,
    Stock_Splits: 0
  },
  {
    Symbol: 'msft',
    Date: '2022-07-26 00:00:00',
    Open: 259.8599853516,
    High: 259.8800048828,
    Low: 249.5700073242,
    Close: 251.8999938965,
    Volume: 38096200,
    Dividends: 0,
    Stock_Splits: 0
  }
]
```

I'm getting the following Output:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ''[{"Symbol":"msft","Date":"2022-07-20
> 00:00:00","Open":259.8999938965,' at line 1 You have an error in
> your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near
> ''[{"Symbol":"msft","Date":"2022-07-20
> 00:00:00","Open":259.8999938965,' at line 1 Error: You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
> ''[{"Symbol":"msft","Date":"2022-07-20
> 00:00:00","Open":259.8999938965,' at line 1
> at PromiseConnection.query

Comment: did you try `db.query(\`INSERT INTO db.AStockHistory VALUES (?)\`, data);`?

Comment: Use INSERT .. SELECT. In SELECT part parse your array to separate rows and column values using JSON_TABLE(). PS. Do not use DOUBLE for integer properties and TEXT for short strings. And, if date value is not local, use DATETIME (if timepart is always zero - use DATE).

Comment: @GrafiCode i tried but the same error.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the idea, i will try that as well. i just saw that this way should work, like i mentioned in the other stackoverflow Question. For that i just wanted to keep it simple. and push it without any further manipulation into the db. But yes ok now i try to getting it done by seperating. The table adjustments, good point. will check that.

Comment: Pay attention! Shown parameter value (array of objects) **IS NOT** valid JSON value from MySQL looking point.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO db.AStockHistory VALUES (?);", [data]);` i'm currently tring this one, but here i get the following error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    at PromiseConnection.query

Comment: He's building inside of the query function of the mysql2 module the following sql which will pushed to the database: `"INSERT INTO db.AStockHistory VALUES ('[{\\\"Symbol\\\":\\\"msft\\\",\\\"Date\\\":\\\"2022-07-20 00:00:00\\\",\\\"Open\\\":259.8999938965,\\\"High\\\":264.8699951172,\\\"Low\\\":258.9100036621,\\\"Close\\\":262.2699890137,\\\"Volume\\\":22788300,\\\"Dividends\\\":0,\\\"Stock_Splits\\\":0}]');"` and that's completly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

for me i found a workaround for my issue and now it works thanks @Akina

```
async function create(stockHistory){
    var response = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < stockHistory.length; i++) {
      var data = stockHistory[i]
      try {
        const result = await db.execute(
          `INSERT INTO db.AStockHistory (Symbol, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Dividends, Stock_Splits) VALUES ('${data.Symbol}', '${data.Date}', ${data.Open}, ${data.High}, ${data.Low}, ${data.Close}, ${data.Volume}, ${data.Dividends}, ${data.Stock_Splits});`); 
      
        if (result.affectedRows) {
          response [i] = 'Stock History Symbol: '+ data.Symbol + ', Date: ' + data.Date +' created successfully';
        }
      } catch {
      response [i] = 'Error in creating Stock History for Symbol: '+ data.Symbol + ', Date: ' + data.Date;
      }
  }
  return {response};
```